# Issue on Adding Class to Element which already Had same Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am trying to add an animation class to on div by using following code and repeating the result on each time click as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#1").on("click",function(){

    $('#layer1').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
    //  $('#layer1').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');

  });
      $("#2").on("click",function(){

    $('#layer1').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');

  });
});
```

but it it seems the process is happeining only one time and I am not able to add the classes animated fadeInLeft even from another call. I also tried to use

```
$('#layer1').removeClass('animated fadeInLeft');
```

after each time adding class but it didn't work either. How can I reset the animation after each time animate?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/GUMx5/)**

Comment: please provide simple demo that incldes css. We have no idea what effect does or what reset you need

Comment: Removing and adding classes won't work as your fadeIn animation is (probably) coming from some plugin that is run once when the document is ready. Give us more code if you want us to help.

Comment: Hi , and thanks for reply Here is a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/GUMx5/

Comment: can do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/GUMx5/1/  I guessed at time frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to remove the `animated` class when animation ends. This should work for you :

```
$("#layer1").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("animated");
})
```

It causes to start animation when `animated` class is added again.